# How to detect flash process in Google Chrome?

Tags: command-line, flash, google-chrome

I'am using this script -- [lightsOn,](https://github.com/iye/lightsOn/blob/master/lightsOn.sh) to delay screensaver when flash playing.

However, the script provides only the *Chromuim* way:

```
flash_process=`pgrep -lfc "chromium-browser --type=plugin --plugin-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin"`
```

I am using the official *Google Chrome* in xfce. Not familiar with shell programming, the screenshot of my process running in *Chrome*.

[image: screenshot of my process running in *Chrome*]

I want to know how to detect the process of flash player to make this script running? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `flash_process=`pgrep -lfc "google-chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin"`` ? (although this might not work because chrome uses its own brand of flash)

Comment: `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so` is what I see in Chrome 23 in `chrome://plugins`.

Comment: @MHC Yeah, I have tried flash_process=pgrep -lfc "google-chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin"``. It doesn't work still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution to disable xscreensaver when flash playing in Chrome.

Firstly, disable shockwave flash plugin  at '/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so' in chrome://plugins as follows:

[image: disable shockwave flash plugin]

Then the command can detect flash process in chrome:

```
flash_process=`pgrep -lfc "chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so"`
```

I have forked the script from *github*, and push the new one with Chrome flash detection.  [Here](https://github.com/zfz/lightsOn/blob/master/lightsOn.sh) is the new script.

Well, the version of my google Chrome:
[image: chrome version]

Answer (score 1):

As Chrome uses the Pepper API, you can find the process referring to the chrome parameter 'type=ppapi'. You can do that using top/htop on the cmd line.

`pgrep -lf "chrome --type=ppapi "`